# Utilizar el valor de una propiedad como tipo - Interfaz Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

### Contexto

Hola, estoy creando una interfaz llamada `UseChartProps` que como su nombre lo indica, son los props que va a recibir un hook de React (específicamente NextJS), es esta:

```
export type ChartOptions = 'bar' | 'doughnut' | 'line' | 'pie' | 'polarArea' | 'radar';

export interface UseChartProps {
  type: ChartOptions;
  labels: (string | number)[];
  datasets: ChartDataset<ChartOptions, number[]>[];
  config: {
    width: string;
    horizontal?: boolean;
    heigth?: string;
    titleSize?: number;
    onClick?: (label: string | number, value: number) => any;
    labelsDisplay?: boolean;
  };
}
```

### Problema

Pasa que todavía no he creado la interfaz que necesito, ¿Por qué? pues porque necesito que el compilador reconozca lo siguiente: **según el valor que se introduzca en la propiedad `type` será el tipo de la propiedad datasets**, me explico:

Si yo en type introduzco `"bar"` el tipo de la propiedad `datasets` debe de ser `ChartDataset<"bar", number[]>[]`

### Soluciones que no me han servido

He tratado de crear la interfaz como un `type` en vez de una `interface` de esta manera:

```
type example {
  type: 'bar'
  datasets: ChartDataset<'bar', number[]>[];
  //demás propiedades...
} | {
  type: 'doughnut'
  datasets: ChartDataset<'doughnut', number[]>[];
  //demás propiedades...
} | {
  //y así sucesivamente
}
```

Pero eso tampoco me ha funcionado, el compilador me sigue dando error en una parte de mi código porque `datasets` sigue asiendo alusión a `ChartOptions` en vez de hacer alusión según lo que ponga en la propiedad `type`

También intenté algo como esto, porque pensé que podía funcionar pero no:

```
export interface UseChartProps {
  type: ChartOptions;
  labels: (string | number)[];
  //                     aquí está el cambio
  datasets: ChartDataset<UseChartProps['type'], number[]>[];
  config: {
    width: string;
    horizontal?: boolean;
    heigth?: string;
    titleSize?: number;
    onClick?: (label: string | number, value: number) => any;
    labelsDisplay?: boolean;
  };
}
```

No sé qué hacer y estoy un tanto desesperado porque es de un proyecto y no quiero estancarme en esto. Gracias de antemano.

Anexo de fotos de lo que dice el compilador con el primer código (el original, el primer código que sale en esta pregunta).
[image: Editor de código]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@cmpnts/*": ["components/*"],
      "@fcns/*": ["functions/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["styles/pages/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@context/*": ["context/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrégale un tipo a la interfaz:

```
export interface UseChartProps<ChartOptions> {
  type: ChartOptions;
  labels: (string | number)[];
  datasets: ChartDataset<ChartOptions, number[]>[];
  config: {
    width: string;
    horizontal?: boolean;
    heigth?: string;
    titleSize?: number;
    onClick?: (label: string | number, value: number) => any;
    labelsDisplay?: boolean;
  };
}
```

Y luego la usas así:

```
let objeto: UserChartProps<'bar'>;
```

Comment: La sintaxis sería: ``UseChartProps<T extends ChartOptions>``. De la forma en la que está ahora mismo podrías pasarle cualquier tipo arbitario a la interfaz y no un tipo específico de ``ChartOptions``

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo efectivamente, es como dices, muchas gracias a los dos